# What is the 'container' node create on merging multiple networks in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I merged 190 networks obtained from KEGG using Cytoscape. The merged network has a node called 'container' that is very highly connected to several other nodes. The node 'container' does not come from the original pathway files. What does this node represent and what is its significance?
[image: Attached is a screenshot showing the node 'container' in yellow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that doesn't come from Cytoscape's merge tool either.  My best guess is that some of your pathways have "container" nodes that wrap a complex or group of genes.  During merge, these would all become the same node.  Even if you don't see a "container" node in the network view, check to see if it appears in the node table anywhere.

-- scooter

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I looked more deeply into this and you are right. Some proteins are grouped together in a 'container' and on merging them the different 'group nodes' are just considered one.